# Can we change the web URL of Android app which is show in URL box when we search app using web browser

Tags: android, url

For example the url is

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xyz.abc

can we change that **id attribute** in url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android, if you want to change the id attribute then you need to change the application package name and need to upload the application again in Google play-store.

But the big problem is :: if you change the application  package name then you are not able to update application in Google play-store. you need to upload application again as new application in Google play-store.